# How to use the Spark Mlib Multilayer Perceptron Weights Array

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have a requirement where i need to find the relative importance of the attributes used in ANN implementation. I use the spark MLib library MultiLayerPerceptron for implementation. The model gives me a vector which is an array of the weights. I know there are algorithms to derive the relative importance from weights , but the MLib implementation gives out a big single dimensional array and does not tell anything about the weights corresponding to each input. Anyone know how to get the weights corresponding to each input node?

Comment: Any answer to this? I have been wondering about the semantic of the weight vector

Answer (score 2):

The [model](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/ann/Layer.scala) flattens the weights matrices with the `Breeze` manipulation: `toDenseVector`. (notice the line: `val brzWeights: BV[Double] = weightsOld.asBreeze.toDenseVector`)

This manipulation [acts like `numpy`'s `flatten()`](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet).
Therefore, to retrieve the weights matrices, you have to do two things:

1. Split the weights vector to parts, according to your layers. You have to take `(layerSize + 1) * nextLayerSize` weights per each non-final layer (`+1` because of the bias).
2. For each flattened weight matrix, apply `numpy`'s `reshape` with parameters `(layerSize + 1, nextLayerSize)`.

When you derive the relative importance from your weights, notice that in the [pyspark implementation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#multilayer-perceptron-classifier), the bias is represented as the last feature: [image: from the docs:].

Therefore the last row in each weight matrix represents the bias value.